# Substitute estimateGeometrictransformation

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I go through the help of matlab and I found out that the function "estimateGeometrictransformation" doesn't support "Briskpoints". How can substute it. I have to implement a code to detect matching points. (like I saw in this example http://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `points` is a `briskPoints` object, you should be able to use `points.Location` to get the x-y coordinates, and pass them to `estimateGeometricTransformation`.